# JavaFX Confused about SetOnEditCommit method

Tags: listview, javafx

I've made a simple to-do list application using JavaFX. After doing some research I figured out how to make the ListView editable (such that double-clicking a cell allows you to change the text inside). Everything works fine as of now, but I am very confused on what role the setOnEditCommit method plays in my code. Here is my entire initialize method, the setOnEditCommit is at the bottom.

```
    public void initialize()
{
    listContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem deleteMenuItem = new MenuItem("Delete");
    deleteMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            TodoItem item = todoListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            deleteItem(item);
        }
    });

    listContextMenu.getItems().addAll(deleteMenuItem);
    todoListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TodoItem>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TodoItem> observable, TodoItem oldValue, TodoItem newValue) {
            if(newValue != null)
            {
                TodoItem item = todoListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                itemDetailsTextArea.setText(item.getDetails());
                DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy");
                deadlineLabel.setText(item.getDeadline().format(df));
            }
        }
    });

    wantAllItems = new Predicate<TodoItem>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(TodoItem todoItem) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    wantTodaysItems = new Predicate<TodoItem>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(TodoItem todoItem) {
            return todoItem.getDeadline().equals(LocalDate.now());
        }
    };
    filteredList = new FilteredList<TodoItem>(TodoData.getInstance().getTodoitems(), wantAllItems);
    SortedList<TodoItem> sortedList = new SortedList<TodoItem>(filteredList,
            new Comparator<TodoItem>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(TodoItem o1, TodoItem o2) {
                    return o1.getDeadline().compareTo(o2.getDeadline());
                }
            });

    //todoListView.setItems(TodoData.getInstance().getTodoitems());
    todoListView.setItems(sortedList);
    todoListView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    todoListView.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

    todoListView.setEditable(true);

    todoListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<TodoItem>, ListCell<TodoItem>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<TodoItem> call(ListView<TodoItem> lv) {
            TextFieldListCell<TodoItem> cell = new TextFieldListCell<TodoItem>(){
                @Override
                public void updateItem(TodoItem item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if(empty){
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        setText(item.getShortDescription());
                        if(item.getDeadline().isBefore(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1)))
                            setTextFill(Color.RED);
                        else if(item.getDeadline().equals(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1)))
                            setTextFill(Color.BROWN);
                    }
                }

            };

            cell.emptyProperty().addListener(
                    (obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) ->
                    {
                        if(isNowEmpty)
                            cell.setContextMenu(null);
                        else
                            cell.setContextMenu(listContextMenu);
                    }
            );

            cell.setConverter(new StringConverter<TodoItem>() {
                @Override
                public String toString(TodoItem object) {
                    return object.toString();
                }

                @Override
                public TodoItem fromString(String string) {
                    cell.getItem().setShortDescription(string);
                    return cell.getItem();
                }
            });
            return cell;
        }
    });

    // this is the method where the source of the exception is being reported
    todoListView.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<ListView.EditEvent<TodoItem>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ListView.EditEvent<TodoItem> e) {
        }
    });
}
```

Now im confused because commenting out the setOnEditCommit method causes an exception. So clearly I need it. However, the overridden handle function inside does nothing, there are no lines of code inside. So why is it necessary to keep this and what does it do? When is this called?

Keep in mind my to-do list functions just fine. The edits are committed and saved so you can see them on the next run. I feel like I am grossly misunderstanding something.

Comment: a converter is just for .. conversion, nothing else - no side-effects allowed

Answer (score 0):

Committing and edit to a `TextFieldListCell` work like this:

- If a `onEditCommit` handler is set, the `ListView` assumes this handler is used to handle the edit.
- If no `onEditCommit` handler is set, the result of converting the `TextField` content to a item using the converter is set at the index of the item in the cell.

Since you use a `SortedList` with the `ListView` calling `set` yields an exception (the list is only a view of a different `ObservableList` and cannot  be directly modified). Setting the `onEditCommit` handler prevents `ListView` from calling `SortedList.set` and thus prevents the error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html):

> By default the ListView edit commit handler is non-null, with a default handler that attempts to overwrite the property value for the item in the currently-being-edited row. ... It is very important to note that if you call `setOnEditCommit(javafx.event.EventHandler)` with your own EventHandler, then you will be removing the default handler.

The `TextFieldListCell`, when you commit the edit, fires a `ListView.EditEvent` event whose `newValue` is the value created by passing the text field's text to the converter's `fromString()` method.

The default `onEditCommit()` handler takes that value and sets it in the list. I.e. it does something along the lines of

```
event.getSource().getItems().set(event.getIndex(), event.getNewValue());
```

Since you are using an *unmodifiable* list (a `SortedList`) as the items list for the `ListView`, trying to set a value in it throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

By explicitly setting the `onEditCommit` handler, you remove the default one, and hence the exception goes away. Since your `converter` actually already does the work of updating the data (which a purist might argue violates separation of concerns), you don't actually need to do anything in this handler.

If your converter were not modifying the item for you (say, e.g., by returning a new `TodoItem`):

```
cell.setConverter(new StringConverter<TodoItem>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(TodoItem object) {
        // shouldn't this return the property that you're editing?
        return object.getShortDescription();
    }

    @Override
    public TodoItem fromString(String string) {
        TodoItem currentItem = cell.getItem();
        TodoItem editedItem = new TodoItem();
        editedItem.setShortDescription(string);
        editedItem.setDeadline(currentItem.getDeadline());
        // etc...
        return editedItem ;
    }
});
```

then you would need your handler to update the backing list, which you could do with

```
todoListView.setOnEditCommit(e -> {
    int indexInSortedList = e.getIndex();
    int indexInFilteredList = sortedList.getSourceIndex(indexInSortedList);
    int indexInOriginalList = filteredList.getSourceIndex(indexInFilteredList);
    TodoData.getInstance().getTodoitems().set(indexInOriginalList, e.getNewValue());
});
```

(assuming the list returned by `getTodoitems()` is modifiable).

Comment: a converter with side-effects (particularly such heavy as updating an item) is plain wrong - not only with my purist hat on ;)

Comment: @kleopatra Agreed.... however if the object in the list has "hidden" properties (ones that aren't displayed in the list), which should persist through an edit, then (as far as I can see) you're forced to pollute the converter to some extent. (Maybe not as far as modifying and returning the existing item, but at best you need to call `cell.getItem()` to examine it for the current values.) So the converter is necessarily coupled to the cell, unless I am missing a trick.

Comment: it (probably, a bit late in the night to really think it through) should return a new item with the the one new and all others same properties .. whatever the problem modifying the existing item under the radar is not a viable option IMO

Comment: @kleopatra That still makes it more than a "converter", imho, but yes, better than the side-effect approach. (And, yes, it's late there...)